# C++ program with derived data type (nested class object) container using MPI/OpenMP

Tags: c++, class, c++11, mpi, openmp

I have developed a program in C++11 and I want to speed up the performance.

I will use a simple example to show the structure of the program (not complete).

```
   //main.cpp
   #include "a.h"
   int main()
   {
     std::vector<a> a_container;
     for (auto i=0; i< 10K; i++)
     {
       a a_obj;
       a_container.push_back(a_obj);
     }

     for(time = 1; time< long_time; time++)
     {
       //i used openmp here already
       for (auto i=0; i< 10K; i++)
       {
         a_container[i].dosomething();
       }
       for (auto i=0; i< 10K; i++)
       {
         a_container[i].update();
       }
     }
     return 1;
   }
   //a.cpp
   //a.h
   #include "b.h"
   class a
   {
     int d;
     b b_obj;
     int dosomething();
   }
   //b.cpp
   //b.h

   class b
   {
      int c;
      double d;
      int dosomething();
   }
```

So in order to speed up the program, I want to use both MPI and OpenMP, mainly for the loop (could be up to 1 million~1 billion instances).

The class object a and b both contain complex member variables (standard and other containers, etc.) and functions.

By using OpenMP, I can take advantage of one HPC node with all cores/threads. But if I want to use MPI, I need to distribute all the instances to many nodes.

I haven't found a good solution to this yet, the closest thing I have right now is;
http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node83.htm#Node83
and https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/how-to-send-cxx-stl-objects-in-mpi
Please provide some suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending non-trivially-copyable objects over MPI is just the same as sending them over any other byte transport: you have to serialize.  You can use `stringstream` to hold the buffer on either end, if it helps.

However, it’s very likely that you shouldn’t do this at all.  The data needed to *create* your objects (*e.g.*, loop bounds and initial values) is probably much smaller and simpler than the form used for ongoing computation.  Send that instead, and you can create your complicated objects in parallel as well as reducing communication.  (If the parameters are known statically, you don’t have to send anything: each process can just start working on the known initialization.)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Based on your second option, I now have a general solution. In order to make use of multiple nodes, I can use MPI to communicate between nodes. Because most member variables can be read or calculated locally, I just need to pass some sort of indices to control the nodes and object instances. With that, I need a Parallel Input/Output (PIO) scheme to allow all nodes can read and write data. The difficult part is that all instances will communicate with other instances during time step, so communication is inevitable, but could be simple structure (stringstream,etc.).